# what is a simple way to create an app that runs in both background and foreground in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a flutter app that sends notification every time there is new entry in stream builder, it works fine when the app is on or opened but I want it to work and receive notification even when it is not opened , I have used workmanager to make the task work in background but it is not working ...the code for it can be found here [code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73112164/19560313)

Answer (score 0):

Flutter apps by nature are supposed to run on a UI thread or foreground. The background tasks you are asking for are features disclosed by each individual platforms.

In case of Android, you can create a a Background Service to accomplish the tasks you need to perform when application is closed. The link to the bacground service is as follows: [Creating a Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service)

In case of iOS, see this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app) for creating a background task. Other platform implementation will be as like above, so please have a look into each platform specific background process.

---

**UPDATE:**

Please have a look into the package [Flutter Background Service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service). This package helps to deal with background tasks setup from flutter side even when app is closed.

**NOTE:**

Q: Why the service not started automatically?
A: Some android device manufacturers have a custom android os for example MIUI from Xiaomi. You have to deal with that policy.

Q: Service killed by system and not respawn? 
A: Try to disable battery optimization for your app.